# Python DataFrame : generate 2 counters in a groupby counter1 from 1 to 3 and counter2 counts everytime counter1 is reset to 1

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, iteration, counter

In pandas dataframe, I'm trying to generate , 2 counters in a df.groupby on type_pgm :

=> counter1 looping from 1 to 3

=> counter2 counts everytime counter1 restart to 1

Here is a df_sample :

```
df_sample = pd.DataFrame([[1,"pgm_1","type_A"],
                          [1,"pgm_1","type_A"],
                          [1,"pgm_1","type_A"],
                          [2,"pgm_2","type_A"],
                          [2,"pgm_2","type_A"],
                          [2,"pgm_2","type_A"],
                          [2,"pgm_2","type_A"],
                          [2,"pgm_2","type_A"],
                          [3,"pgm_3","type_B"],
                          [3,"pgm_3","type_B"],
                          [3,"pgm_3","type_B"],
                          [3,"pgm_3","type_B"],
                          [4,"pgm_4","type_B"]
                          ])

df_sample.columns = ["pgm_id","pgm_name","pgm_type"]

print(df_sample)
```

```
    pgm_id pgm_name pgm_type
0        1    pgm_1   type_A
1        1    pgm_1   type_A
2        1    pgm_1   type_A
3        2    pgm_2   type_A
4        2    pgm_2   type_A
5        2    pgm_2   type_A
6        2    pgm_2   type_A
7        2    pgm_2   type_A
8        3    pgm_3   type_B
9        3    pgm_3   type_B
10       3    pgm_3   type_B
11       3    pgm_3   type_B
12       4    pgm_4   type_B
```

Here is the targeted df_target :

```
df_target = pd.DataFrame([[1,"pgm_1","type_A",1,1],
                          [1,"pgm_1","type_A",2,1],
                          [1,"pgm_1","type_A",3,1],
                          [2,"pgm_2","type_A",1,2],
                          [2,"pgm_2","type_A",2,2],
                          [2,"pgm_2","type_A",3,2],
                          [2,"pgm_2","type_A",1,3],
                          [2,"pgm_2","type_A",2,3],
                          [3,"pgm_3","type_B",1,1],
                          [3,"pgm_3","type_B",2,1],
                          [3,"pgm_3","type_B",3,1],
                          [3,"pgm_3","type_B",1,2],
                          [4,"pgm_4","type_B",2,2]
                          ])

df_target.columns = ["pgm_id","pgm_name","pgm_type","counter1","counter2"]

print(df_target)
```

```
    pgm_id pgm_name pgm_type  counter1  counter2
0        1    pgm_1   type_A         1         1
1        1    pgm_1   type_A         2         1
2        1    pgm_1   type_A         3         1
3        2    pgm_2   type_A         1         2
4        2    pgm_2   type_A         2         2
5        2    pgm_2   type_A         3         2
6        2    pgm_2   type_A         1         3
7        2    pgm_2   type_A         2         3
8        3    pgm_3   type_B         1         1
9        3    pgm_3   type_B         2         1
10       3    pgm_3   type_B         3         1
11       3    pgm_3   type_B         1         2
12       4    pgm_4   type_B         1         2
```

I tried many ways unsuccessfull...

Thanks a lot in advance for your help

Comment: If you only groupby `pgm_type`, shouldn't then be the value in the last row of counter1 `2`?

Comment: Tkx Rabinzel. I tryed a groupby pgm_type count but it counts the whole list of type_A then type_B. like this df_sample['counter1'] = df_sample.groupby('pgm_type')['pgm_type'].transform('count'). The target is to reset that counter1 when reaching 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question right:

```py
df_sample["counter1"] = (
    df_sample.groupby(["pgm_type", "pgm_name"])
    .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(i % 3 + 1 for i in range(len(x))))
    .values
)

df_sample["counter2"] = (
    df_sample.groupby("pgm_type")
    .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(i // 3 + 1 for i in range(len(x))))
    .values
)

print(df_sample)
```

Prints:

```
    pgm_id pgm_name pgm_type  counter1  counter2
0        1    pgm_1   type_A         1         1
1        1    pgm_1   type_A         2         1
2        1    pgm_1   type_A         3         1
3        2    pgm_2   type_A         1         2
4        2    pgm_2   type_A         2         2
5        2    pgm_2   type_A         3         2
6        2    pgm_2   type_A         1         3
7        2    pgm_2   type_A         2         3
8        3    pgm_3   type_B         1         1
9        3    pgm_3   type_B         2         1
10       3    pgm_3   type_B         3         1
11       3    pgm_3   type_B         1         2
12       4    pgm_4   type_B         1         2
```

Comment: Tkx Andrej for taking time to have a look on this. Appreciate.  When trying your way, I'm facing the error message : "'Series' object has no attribute 'value' 
None" ... Any idea why ?

Comment: Andrej thanks a lot ! It solved my issue. I'd made a bad syntaxe when first tried to reproduce your way but It works as perfect :)